# How to find a control inside a listview from a button click which is outside in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I hava an imagebutton. when clicking on the imagebutton i want to show or hide the check box which is present inside the listview. what I tried is given below.

**Button**

```
 <ImageButton Source="plus.png"   x:Name="imgBtnPlus" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,10,0" Clicked="imgBtnPlus_Clicked" />
```

**Listview**

```
<ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding NewOrders}" x:Name="lstNewOrders" ItemTapped="lstNewOrders_ItemTapped" RowHeight="80" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid BackgroundColor="#fefefe" Padding="10">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="60"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="bluecircle.png" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="Start"></Image>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0, 0, 0, 5" VerticalOptions="Center">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Text="{Binding number}" FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="18" x:Name="lblNumber" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding Description}"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="12" />
                    </Grid>
                                   
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="False" Grid.Column="2" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="chklstNew" Style="{StaticResource ckhMultipleOrders}" />
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Code behind**

when i tried to access the checkbox like this I am getting null always. can anybody help?

```
private void imgBtnPlus_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chk = lstNewOrders.FindByName("chklstNew") as CheckBox;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

From the shared code , you haven't made full use of ***MVVM*** in Xamarin Forms. There are two ways to define the `IsShow` property of Model.

**One way** is to declare a `IsShow` attribute for the ViewModel (Binded for ContentPage).

For example , the ViewModel as follow :

```
public class CheckModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public List<CheckItem> NewOrders { get; set; }

    private bool checkShow;
    public bool CheckShow
    {
        set
        {
            if (checkShow != value)
            {
                checkShow = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CheckShow");
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return checkShow;
        }
    }
    public CheckModel()
    {
        CheckShow = false;
        NewOrders = new List<CheckItem>();
        NewOrders.Add(new CheckItem() { Number = "1", Description = "1 description"});
        NewOrders.Add(new CheckItem() { Number = "2", Description = "2 description"});
        NewOrders.Add(new CheckItem() { Number = "3", Description = "3 description"});
        NewOrders.Add(new CheckItem() { Number = "4", Description = "4 description"});
        NewOrders.Add(new CheckItem() { Number = "5", Description = "5 description"});
    }


    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And used in ContentPage as follow :

```
public partial class PageListViewCheckBox : ContentPage
{
    CheckModel checkModel;
    public PageListViewCheckBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        checkModel = new CheckModel();
        BindingContext = checkModel;
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (checkModel.CheckShow)
        {
            checkModel.CheckShow = false;
        }
        else
        {
            checkModel.CheckShow = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The Xaml code as follow：

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout x:Name="ContentPage">
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
            VerticalOptions="Start" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Button Text="ShowOrNo" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
        <ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding NewOrders}"
                   x:Name="lstNewOrders"
                   RowHeight="80">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid BackgroundColor="#fefefe"
                              Padding="10"
                              x:Name="grid">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="60"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Image Source="bluecircle.png"
                                   Grid.Column="0"
                                   Grid.Row="0"
                                   VerticalOptions="Start"></Image>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="1"
                                  Grid.Row="0"
                                  Margin="0, 0, 0, 5"
                                  VerticalOptions="Center">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Number}"
                                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                                       Grid.Column="0"
                                       Grid.Row="0"
                                       FontSize="18"
                                       x:Name="lblNumber" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Description}"
                                       Grid.Column="0"
                                       Grid.Row="1"
                                       FontSize="12" />
                            </Grid>

                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"
                                      Grid.Column="2"
                                      VerticalOptions="Center"
                                      Grid.Row="0"
                                      x:Name="chklstNew"
                                      IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Reference ContentPage}, Path=BindingContext.CheckShow}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

You will see the `IsVisible` of **CheckBox** is binded to the `BindingContext` of **ContentPage**.

The effect:

[image]

**The another way** is to declare a `IsShow` attribute for cell item model.

For example , the listview cell model is:

```
public class CheckItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Number { set; get; }
    public string Description { set; get; }

    private bool checkIsShow;
    public bool CheckIsShow
    {
        set
        {
            if (checkIsShow != value)
            {
                checkIsShow = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CheckIsShow");
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return checkIsShow;
        }
    }

    private bool isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        set
        {
            if (isChecked != value)
            {
                isChecked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return isChecked;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then the ViewModel modified as follow:

```
public class CheckModel 
{
    public List<CheckItem> NewOrders { get; set; }

    public CheckModel()
    {
        NewOrders = new List<CheckItem>();
        NewOrders.Add(new CheckItem() { Number = "1", Description = "1 description", CheckIsShow = false });
        NewOrders.Add(new CheckItem() { Number = "2", Description = "2 description", CheckIsShow = false });
        NewOrders.Add(new CheckItem() { Number = "3", Description = "3 description", CheckIsShow = false });
        NewOrders.Add(new CheckItem() { Number = "4", Description = "4 description", CheckIsShow = false });
        NewOrders.Add(new CheckItem() { Number = "5", Description = "5 description", CheckIsShow = false });
    }
}
```

The **Xaml** code ,only modify the `CheckBox` code as follow:

```
...
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"
            Grid.Column="2"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            Grid.Row="0"
            x:Name="chklstNew"
            IsVisible="{Binding CheckIsShow}"/>
 ...
```

Now the ContentPage as follow:

```
public partial class PageListViewCheckBox : ContentPage
{
    CheckModel checkModel;
    public PageListViewCheckBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        checkModel = new CheckModel();
        BindingContext = checkModel;
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(var item in checkModel.NewOrders)
        {
            if (item.CheckIsShow)
            {
                item.CheckIsShow = false;
            }
            else
            {
                item.CheckIsShow = true;
            }
        }

}
```

The effect is the same as above.

Note: Here you will see that the `IsChecked` of **CheckBox** also binded to the ViewModel.That will be helpful to know which item is be selected by using `MVVM`.

Comment: @Amenda If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `FindByName`, hence I cannot tell if it works on a `ListView` to get its children, but if it did, there would be **multiple `CheckBox` instances** within the `ListView`, for basically, the `ListView` takes what's inside the `DataTemplate` and *repeats* it. So *if* it worked, it would rather be an array or `IEnumerable` of `CheckBox` instances, hence `as CheckBox` will of course be `null`.

Having said that, I think you are overcomplicating things. Since you are using bindings, I assume that you already use *MVVM* of sorts, why not use that for showing/hiding your checkboxes?

Just add a property `bool ShowCheckBoxes` (or whatever - just give it a meaningful name) with a change notification (`INotifyPropertyChanged`, but if you are using MVVM already this should be familiar) and a command `public Command OnFooBarButtonClickedCommand { get; set; }` (again: meaningful names!) to your vm. In the method the command calls, just set the `ShowCheckBoxes` property

```cs
private void OnFooBarButtonClicked()
{
    ShowCheckBoxes = true; // or whatever
}
```

Finally, you can update your XAML to make use of that property. Anyway, you can't simply use `{Binding ShowCheckBoxes}` for that purpose, since the binding context of the checkbox is the item in the list. Anyway, there is a `Source` property you can use for that. Just give your Page or topmost view a name, e.g. `x:Name="Page"` if it is a page, now you can reference this element as the source in `Binding`

```xml
<CheckBox IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Reference Page}, Path=BindingContext.ShowCheckBoxes}" 
          IsChecked="False" 
          Grid.Column="2" 
          VerticalOptions="Center" 
          Grid.Row="0"
          Style="{StaticResource ckhMultipleOrders}" />
```

Comment: Thanks @Paul Kertscher, I will try this way